# Store data fetch in a local state redux reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to store date of a fetch in local state and not in the global store of my app.

```
(...)
.then(response => response.json())
.then (data => dispatch(fetchSuccess(data)))
```

And then :

```
export const FETCH_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_SUCCESS';
function fetchSuccess(create) {
    return {type : FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: create}
}
```

I have my data in the reducer with this :

```
const initialState = {
   eCreate: ''
};
case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, eCreate: action.payload}
```

And after I have my state here in my component :

```
rEvt : state.redu.eCreate
```

And I can display with :

```
console.log(rEvt)
```

But my state eCreate is available in all my app. I just want that this state was available just in this component. How can i do this ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: your state value will be available only in the components where you do a ```mapStateToProps``` with```state.redu.eCreate``` sent to props of this component

Comment: I have this in my mapStateToProps : 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    rEvt : state.redu.eCreate
})

Comment: yes, so that means you can get the state value in this component but not in every component

Comment: Don't understand: when I go to another page of my app, the state is still there and there are the "old" data in

Comment: your state value can't be displayed on your app, if you're not using ```mapStateToProps``` in the involved component, if you only need a value in one component you can just use local states without Redux

Comment: Yes it is my question so how can i use juste local states to display my value in one component with the result of my fetch ?

Comment: if you're sure you will need the result of the fetch in only one component of your app, you can do the fetch in a function inside your component... if you know how to use Redux you're supposed to know how to do it, it's easier

Comment: I use this result to make a conditionnal redirection : if the result of my fetch is equal to the result of a user entry in the page A so redirect to another page (page B). My problem : when I want to return back (pageA), I still stay on the page B because the app consider the equality still there. That's why I wanted to proceed differently. But perhaps it is not the right way ?

Comment: can you show the full code of your component

Comment: My code in the next answer

Answer (score 0):

My component

```
function Create(props) {

    const {cEvt, sEvt, gtf, rEvt} = props;

    console.log(rEvt)


    if (rEvt.name === sEvt)
    {
        return <Redirect to={"/d/" + rEvt.name} />
    }


    return (
        <div >
            <input type="text" value={sEvt} onChange={e => cEvt(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={() => gtf(sEvt)} >Go !</button>

        </div>
    );
}
```

And the container of my compo :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    sEvt : state.redu.sCreate,
    rEvt : state.redu.eCreate
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    cEvt : e => dispatch(changeInput(e)),
    gtf : (name) => dispatch(fetchCreate(name))
})
```

My fetch has a method POST to create a new entry with the name of the input.